# Different behaviors between C and Rust code snippets

Tags: c, rust, pipe, fork, posix

I have a C code snippet which uses `pipe()` and `fork()` to communicate between parent and child process. I want to replicate it in Rust. For the POSIX APIs used in C, if there are counterparts in the Rust standard library, they are preferred.

However, these two code snippets have different behaviors. What is the root cause of these different behaviors?

###### C code snippet

```c
// error handling is omitted for simplicity's sake

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CHILD_MESS "Child: I wanna cookie\n"
#define PAR_MESS "Parent: testing...\n"

int main() {
    int pipe_fd[2] = {-1, -1};    
    int len = 0;
    char buf[100] = {'\0'};
    int read_len = 0;
    
    pipe(pipe_fd);
    
    switch (fork()) {
        case 0:  // in the child
            len = strlen(CHILD_MESS);
            while(1) {
                write(pipe_fd[1], CHILD_MESS, len);
                sleep(5);
            }
            break; 
        default:  // in the parent
            len = strlen(PAR_MESS);
            while(1) {
                write(pipe_fd[1], PAR_MESS, len);
                sleep(1);
                read_len = read(pipe_fd[0], buf, 100);
                if (read_len <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                write(1, buf, read_len);
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

###### Rust code snippet

```rust
use nix::unistd::{fork, pipe, ForkResult};  // needs extern crate `nix`
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::os::unix::io::{FromRawFd, RawFd};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

const CHILD_MSG: &str = "Child: I wanna cookie\n";
const PAR_MSG: &str = "Parent: testing...\n";

fn main() {
    let (read_end, write_end): (RawFd, RawFd) = pipe().unwrap();
    let mut buf: [u8; 100] = [0; 100];
    let mut read_end: File = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(read_end) };
    let mut write_end: File = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(write_end) };

    match unsafe { fork() } {
        Ok(res) => match res {
            ForkResult::Child => loop {
                write_end.write_all(CHILD_MSG.as_bytes()).expect("write");
                sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
            },
            ForkResult::Parent { child: _ } => loop {
                write_end.write_all(PAR_MSG.as_bytes()).expect("write");
                sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                let n = read_end.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
                if n == 0 {
                    break;
                }
                print!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());
            },
        },
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is something like:

```sh
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out
Parent: testing...
Child: I wanna cookie
Parent: testing...
Parent: testing...
Parent: testing...
Parent: testing...    // Five seconds elapsed
Child: I wanna cookie
Parent: testing...
...
```

```
After execution:
One second elapsed:    print `Parent: testing...\nChild: I wanna cookie\n` 
Two seconds elapsed:   print `Parent: testing...`
Three seconds elapsed: print `Parent: testing...`
...
Five seconds elapsed:  print `Parent: testing...\nChild: I wanna cookie\n`
...
```

However, for the Rust code snippet I get something like this:

```
$ cargo run -q
Parent: testing...
Child: I wanna cookie
Parent: testing...
Child: I wanna cookie
...
```

```
After execution:
One second elapsed:    print `Parent: testing...\nChild: I wanna cookie\n` 
Two second elapsed:    print `Parent: testing...\nChild: I wanna cookie\n` 
Three seconds elapsed:  print `Parent: testing...\nChild: I wanna cookie\n`
...
```

It just print `Parent: testing...\nChild: I wanna cookie\n` every second

My environment:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux pop-os 5.17.5-76051705-generic #202204271406~1651504840~22.04~63e51bd SMP PREEMPT Mon May 2 15: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3) 2.35
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.60.0 (7737e0b5c 2022-04-04)
```

Comment: Pipes aren't really duplex communication channels. One process writes and *only* writes, while another process reads and *only* reads. If you need to read and write in the same process, you need *two* pipes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Thanks for the tip, I do read and write to the channel within the same process. Will this trigger UB or somthing? If so, maybe this is the cause for the different behaviors?

Comment: No UB (not directly anyway), but as you see from your behavior what you write will be read back in the same process. You can't use it to communicate with a different process reliably. Also, since you sometimes read the message from the child-process, you might skip one of the parent process messages, slowly filling up the pipe until no process can write to the pipe, and leading to a *deadlock*. What is the purpose of writing to the pipe from the parent process anyway?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude .  Thanks for your explanation! I feel sorry about my improper usage of `pipe`. Actually, this `C code snippet` is a demo code from the book Understanding Unix/Linux Programming and perhaps is just for demo purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between them lies in the fact that `print!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf).unwrap());` will flush the whole `buf` to stdout, whereas `write(1, buf, read_len);` will just write `read_len` bytes.

If we change `write(1, buf, read_len);` to `write(1, buf, 100);` in C or use `stdout().write(&buf[0..n]).unwrap();` in Rust they have the same behavior.